# How to compare two timestamp field's difference with a particular interval of time in Spark SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I searched quite a bit and didn't find a solution to compare a time interval with a difference between two timestamp fields in plain Spark SQL as a query.

Below is the native PostgreSQL code which works like a charm:

```
case 
    when t1.prev_time <> t1.prev_time_calc and t1."Timestamp" - t1.prev_time < interval '30 min' 
      then t1.next_time_calc - t1.prev_time_calc
    when (t1.next_time <> t1.next_time_calc and t1.next_time - t1."Timestamp" < interval '30 min') or (t1.next_time - t1."Timestamp" < interval '30 min')
      then t1.next_time_calc - t1."Timestamp"
  else null
  end min_diff
```

Below is the error I get in Spark if I run as is:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
No interval can be constructed(line 6, pos 99)

== SQL ==
select
  t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.next_time_calc, t1.next_time,
  case 
    when t1.prev_time <> t1.prev_time_calc and ((t1.Timestamp - t1.prev_time) < INTERVAL '30 min') 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
      then t1.next_time_calc - t1.prev_time_calc
    when (t1.next_time <> t1.next_time_calc and t1.next_time - t1.Timestamp < INTERVAL '30 min') or ((t1.next_time - t1.Timestamp) < INTERVAL '30 min')
      then t1.next_time_calc - t1.Timestamp
  else null
  end min_diff
```

As you can see, I removed quotes, I removed interval keyword and so on and so forth to try out, but not working, how to do this?

My Spark SQL code:

```
oper_n_qc_working_hrs_df2 = spark.sql("""select
  t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.next_time_calc, t1.next_time,
  case 
    when t1.prev_time <> t1.prev_time_calc and ((t1.Timestamp - t1.prev_time) < INTERVAL '30 min') 
      then t1.next_time_calc - t1.prev_time_calc
    when (t1.next_time <> t1.next_time_calc and t1.next_time - t1.Timestamp < INTERVAL '30 min') or ((t1.next_time - t1.Timestamp) < INTERVAL '30 min')
      then t1.next_time_calc - t1.Timestamp
  else null
  end min_diff
  from oper_n_qc_working_hrs_df1 t1""")
```

Versions:
Spark: 2.4
Python: 3.7

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with:

**INTERVAL 30 MINUTES** rather than *INTERVAL 30 mins* in the query.